# How to correctly implement Apple Pay in a C#/.NET environment using Payment Request API?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, applepay

I've been trying to follow this guide

https://webkit.org/blog/8182/introducing-the-payment-request-api-for-apple-pay/

to implement Apple Pay on our website using the Payment Request API. However, one of the first steps is to call Apple Pay JS's "ApplePaySession" - Apparently, in order to do this i would need to declare `interface ApplePaySession` but apparently this can only be done in a typescript file? I am working within VS as an intern in a primarily C#/.NET backend with a javascript front end and I'm kind of lost.

I guess my question is, is there any way to use the Payment Request API without having to use the Apple Pay JS API also? And if not, how exactly would I go about declaring the ApplePaySession? Am I good to go with the rest of the guide once I do that?

Comment: Did you ever succeed with this?